# Getting ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'management' issue in Random Forest classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning

Creating Random Forest classifier Model to fetch accuracy score data . In File it consist of numeric , float , string type data.
Getting an issue: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'management'`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random 
from sklearn import metrics

data = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\train.csv")  # reading csv file #
#data.head(10)
X = data.iloc[:, 0:17].values
y = data.iloc[:, 4].values


from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)


from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=5)
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)


from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

print(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-ba110d6d76aa> in <module>
     28 
     29 clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=5)
---> 30 clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
     31 y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
     32 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\forest.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    247 
    248         # Validate or convert input data
--> 249         X = check_array(X, accept_sparse="csc", dtype=DTYPE)
    250         y = check_array(y, accept_sparse='csc', ensure_2d=False, dtype=None)
    251         if sample_weight is not None:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    494             try:
    495                 warnings.simplefilter('error', ComplexWarning)
--> 496                 array = np.asarray(array, dtype=dtype, order=order)
    497             except ComplexWarning:
    498                 raise ValueError("Complex data not supported\n"

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    536 
    537     """
--> 538     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    539 
    540 

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'management'
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment so i post here.

First, just to make sure :

```py
## I think you missed a 'd' in that variable name
ata = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\train.csv")
```

I think you should provide us with a sample of your input data. It seems that one of you columns contains a specific type of data raising `ValueError("Complex data not supported\n")`

In general, when importing data and before feeding your algorythm with it, you should always do some basic pre-processing at least to ensure that data formats are correct.

Comment: its data by mistakenly it is ata

Comment: but still getting same issue

Comment: I thought so :) Could you edit your question with ,as i requested, some insight on your input data ? Present at least a full row.